# How to delete a line in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
f = open('국민 시력 통계.csv')
sight = csv.reader(f)
next(sight)
f = open('국민 시력 통계.csv')
sight = csv.reader(f)
hsight = []
next(sight)
for see in sight:
    try:
        hsight.append(float(see[-1]))
    except:
        pass
print(hsight)
hsight.sort(reverse=True)
hsight
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iDEA8jFaQxcHpKevPpXsdKeIXv3ezOqu

This is a link to the csv file.
I need to find a way to delete the 9.9 variable...
Don't know how.

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with the question?  What have you written to try and solve the problem?

Comment: Please post the CSV file as either a link to a paste service (definitely not something that requires logging in) or include a snippet in your post. Also, "plz help" doesn't encourage others to help you, just a word of advice. Take some time, re-think this post, and edit when you've thought better.

Comment: @connectyourcharger: It doesn't work even if you log in (to your own account) — some kind of permissions error. So it doesn't appear to have been done correctly the way it is anyway.

Comment: @martineau Hopefully OP realizes that and edits accordingly... *ahem ahem*

Answer (score 0):

Read csv as a pandas dataframe. Look into few rows and see its shape, check for any null values etc. LOOK into data before doing anything first.

I guess line and you said variable so here means you want to delete a column.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('국민 시력 통계.csv', header=0) # If csv has header or None
print('dataframe shape:', df.shape)
df.head() # Look first five rows to get a rough understanding
df=df.drop(columns=['9.9']) # Not sure though works if your columnname 9.9
```

Please repost your question with correct aim, as to what you want.

Thanks.

Comment: The OP asks how to delete a _line_, not a column (and mentioned nothing about `pandas`).

Comment: I suggested to look it as a pandas dataframe. Just a different point of view.